# rails 3 where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

In rails 3, the where statement of active record returns an active record object. i.e it uses lazy loading like

```
cars = Car.where(:colour => 'black') # No Query
cars.each {|c| puts c.name } # Fires "select * from cars where ..."
```

but when I fires,

```
cars = Car.where(:colour => 'black')
```

in console, it returns the result without this lazy loading why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console implicitly calls `inspect` on the result of your expression, which triggers the query.

You can avoid the inspection by appending a semicolon:

```
cars = Car.where(:colour => 'black');
```

Comment: I'd suggest it's better to append `;nil` as a general practice. `;` doesn't execute the code until the next statement is entered.